# Terraform GCP instance from machine-image in different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

On the GCP CLI , I can create a VM in "project-a" from a machine-image in "project-b":

(**from "project-a" cloud shell**)

```
gcloud beta compute instances create new-vm-name   --project=project-a     --zone=us-east4-a    --source-machine-image=projects/project-b/global/machineImages/image-name  --service-account=12345678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com     --network=net-name    --subnet=subnet-name
```

However, in Terraform, this is failing. This is my TF code:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_from_machine_image" "tpl" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = "${var.project_short_name}-admin"
  project  = var.project_id
  zone     = "us-east4-a"
  network_interface {
    network    = module.vpc.network_self_link
    subnetwork = module.vpc.subnets_self_links[0]
  }
  source_machine_image = "image-from-project-b"
  // Override fields from machine image
  can_ip_forward = false
  labels = {
    image = "05-apr-2022"
  }
```

This is my error message:

Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].source
Disk must be in the same project as the instance or instance template., invalid

Can anyone help me determine if TF can even do this (docs seem to say yes) or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I am seeing this now in the TF docs for google_compute_instance_from_machine_image: "Warning:
*Due to API limitations, disk overrides are currently disabled. This includes the "boot_disk", "attached_disk", and "scratch_disk" fields."  --could this be the issue?

Comment: What is the link?

Comment: this is the verbatim error: Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].source': 'projects/liproj-prod-clone1-cloudapp/zones/us-east4-a/disks/liproj-prod-clone1-cloudapp-admin'. Disk must be in the same project as the instance or instance template., invalid

Comment: the "project" in that link from error msg is the project where the machine-image is from; my TF init/plan/apply is in the target project where I want the VM.

Comment: The link to the document you referenced in your comment **I am seeing this now in the TF docs for  ...**

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_from_machine_image

Comment: Are you certain that your provider is configured for the same project that you are specifying in the variable used for the resource argument?

Comment: yes, the provider is google-beta and is configured for the same project